# R working with big decimal numbers

Tags: r

I'm trying print to console or even inspect the numbers inside my dataframe object that contains big decimal numbers with 8 decimal places such as: "1054792997932.50564756" (the class of the number is `numeric`)

I tried using `print()` and `cat()` and `View()` to inspect a single number but the only result I get back is and integer "1054792997932" and the decimal places cannot be seen unless I use `sprintf("%.8f", number)` but the output I get back is the wrong number:

```
> sprintf("%.8f", 1054792997932.50564756)
[1] "1054792997932.50561523"
```

So from the looks of it `sprintf` is not a good method to use to check or format big decimal numbers.

I'm having problems validating and working with rounding such numbers any advice/help you can provide on how to deal with numbers in R would be appreciated as I am stuck

The system setup is:

```
R version: 3.4.0
```

I use pretty standard packages:

```
R stats and R Utils
```

Comment: I suggest you study this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059

Comment: @LAP your example worked for displaying, thanks thats really useful, is there a way to use round with big numbers as well as we tried the following and it didn't work "> round(105479299792.675994873, 4)" => "[1] 105479299792.675994873"

Comment: Interesting. Your example works for me when rounding to either 1 or 0 decimals, but for more decimals it always displays `105479299792.67599`. I'm not sure why this does not work. It may be an artifact due to floating point arithmetic (see link @Roland provided).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, @LAP f you could raise your response as an answer I will accept it, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the number of digits displayed in the console with the option `"digits"`.

To view your current setting, type

```
getOption("digits")
```

The default setting is 7. With

```
options("digits" = 22)
```

you can change the setting. `22` is the maximum amount of digits `R` can display.